# How can solve Record sound problem in android api 26

Tags: android, audio

I Have one app in which I am recording sound . App is working fine in <=Api 25 but not in 26 or higher.

Bit of code:

```
      startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND"), REQUEST_CODE_RECORD);
```

Logcat:

```
W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4501)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4459)
        at com.clogica.mp3cutter.activity.RingtoneEditActivity.onCreate(RingtoneEditActivity.java:267)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7013)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7004)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems on some devices, there is no application to record sound. You should check whether there is a sound record application or not before starting it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_RECORD);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No sound record application found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @ProgrammingofCricketer if there is no record sound app found then you must install an app on that device which matches `android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND` action. Otherwise there is nothing you can do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to define the permission in the manifest, if not done already.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

However, this issue indicates that there is no default media recorder set up on the device running the later API version.

While you may have a default recorder app on the device, it might not explicitly be defined to map to that specific intent.

You could add your own via a new activity and add recording logic.
To specify this you can specify an intent filter similar to:

```
<activity
    android:name="my.audio.RecorderActivity"
    android:label="@string/recorder_activity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
 private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    recorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
}
```

for example code 
 https://github.com/manishtheandroider/VoiceRecorderApp